# Rsyslog central logging separate local logs

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

I have an Rsyslog central server where multiple machine send log files and these log files are stored by machine IP.

```
$template DailyPerHostLogs,"/var/log/remote/%fromhost-ip%_%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%.log"
*.* -?DailyPerHostLogs
```

This works fine however all the logs gets into the logmachines central logs as well like:

```
/var/log/messages
/var/log/auth 
/var/log/cron
```

What is the best way to stop this from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Solved it, have to put the remote log acception rule first then this:

```
## before going to local log rules, drop remote logging, it's been
## processed in the "central logging" section
#
:hostname, !isequal, "biglogserver"       ~
```

Then rest of the rsyslog.conf

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you won't save the logs locally on the machines.

To do that you must remove from `/etc/syslog.conf` all the lines that describe local log files, and leave there only the line that send the logs remotely.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear at the first place. No you misunderstand it.

I talk about this central syslog server itself.

The problem is that the remote logs are mixing into the machines local syslog as well. They are separated by IP all right but they get into the machines main log files.